# Add multiple domain/IPs to SPF record to support google and third part senders

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

We are using Google Apps as email provider and have added following SPF record for our domain

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr include:_spf.google.com -all
```

We also use LivePerson as a support system and when they send email on our behalf from using our domain it fails sometime.

So how can I add their IPs to our SPF record too

```
mails01.liveperson.net 70.42.153.203
mails02.liveperson.net 70.42.153.232
mails03.liveperson.net 70.42.153.233
mails04.liveperson.net 70.42.153.234
maile01.liveperson.net 70.42.153.211
```

We get following error

> e-mail delivery failed for site 62197336, id=mailTicket
>   "\"LTK121620451004X\" \"380116582\" \"Acknowledge\" \"1\"",
>   to=xyz@gmail.com, error=550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from
>   abc.com is not accepted due to domain's 550-5.7.1 DMARC policy.
>   Please contact administrator of abc.com domain if 550-5.7.1 this
>   was a legitimate mail. Please visit 550-5.7.1 
>   http://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about DMARC 550
>   5.7.1 initiative.

Comment: Is `abc.com` what you substituted for your domain or are you actually sending mail from `abc.com`?  It's better to use `example.com` for this purpose.  There's actually an RFC about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr ip4:70.42.153.203 ip4:70.42.153.211 ip4:70.42.153.232 ip4:70.42.153.233 ip4:70.42.153.234 include:_spf.google.com -all
```

If you figured these sender addresses out on your own, I would recommend that you ask LivePerson what you should include in your SPF records. Chances are they have a central record (like google has `_spf.google.com`) that you can include instead of having every possible IP address explicitly stated in your own SPF record